# Check if a directory contains a particular subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell script, which checks if a given directory contains a particularly named subdirectory. I am passing the Parent directory as a first argument and only the name for the child directory. I want the script to go through the contents of the Parent and see if it contains a file of type directory, which is named with the name I am passing in for Child.

This is my code. In it I am trying to pipe the output of `ls` on the Parent to the `egrep` command. I am trying to write a regular expression that checks to see if the output of `ls` has a name that matches (not identically. just somewhere in its name) my child name.

```
PARENT=$1
CHILD=$2

DIRNUM=$(ls -l $PARENT | egrep -c '< $CHILD >')
echo $DIRNUM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Just check for the file/directory directly with the [`[`/`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) built-in/command.

```
path=$parent/$child
if [ -d "$path" ]; then
    echo "$path exists."
else
    echo "$path does not exist."
fi
```

You'll note that I switched case on the variable names. ALL_UPPER variables are "reserved" for the shell's use you shouldn't use any.

Comment: Add a trailing slash to the path to ensure that it is indeed a directory (rather than a file). Or use the -d test rather than -e.

Comment: can you collaborate a bit further on how this works?

Comment: @jwatkins Indeed. I'd missed the "child is a directory" part of the OP.

Comment: @KannyBros What part are you having trouble with specifically? I linked to a man page for the only really "new" bit here (the `[`/`test` command). The rest is just an `if` statement and realizing that you can check directly instead of messing around parsing output from a command that isn't meant for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the find command like the following:

```
# find $parent -name \*${child}\* -and -type d
```

The type option is to insure that the found name is a directory.

This command will find all sub-directories located within $parent that contain $child in its name

Comment: Note that this will *recursively* find subdirectories with that name.To find only immediate subdirectories `-depth 1` is needed